# How can I test a model with rspec that has after_create callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-test

I have this model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_in_remote

  def create_in_remote
   if self.remote_id.nil?
    req_url = "api/create/user/#{self.username}"
    response = Remote.execute_request(req_url)
    if response
      self.update_attribute(:remote_id, response["id"]) if response["id"]
    end
   end
  end
end
```

In my spec I try to do this

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  before { @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user) }

  subject { @user }


  it "has_remote_id" do
    @user.save! && @user.reload
    expect(@user.remote_id).not_to be_nil
  end
end
```

but never passes the test but the object is always created on the remote api. If I want to see the value of the attribute remote_id of the @user object is always null. If I change build to create in the factory, i can see in the log that the attribute is updated, but when use in the test it is null and fail the test.

Comment: I would print out the response in create_in_remote to see if I am getting the response and response["id"].  I would also print out the user object in the test and also try calling user.reload to make sure it is the current state of the object.

Answer (score 5):

Try this to ensure that the callback is called and expect(user.remote_ip).to eq(...) - to check remote_ip

```
describe 'after_create' do
  before { @user = User.new }
  it 'run the create_in_remote callback' do
    expect(@user).to receive(:create_in_remote) 
    @user.run_callbacks(:create) 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax in your test looks wrong. Rspec introduced the `expect` syntax so that instead of this:

```
foo.should eq(bar)
foo.should_not eq(bar)
```

you can do this:

```
expect(foo).to eq(bar)
expect(foo).not_to eq(bar)
```

You're mixing `expect` with `should` so I imagine this is causing your test to fail.

Here's a good blog post about [Rspec's new expectation syntax](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

You should change expectation as @benjaminjosephw suggests.

But I think you have another problem in your spec. When you create `user` it is really has `remote_id` equals to nil (I mean after building but before creating). When you create `user` you update attribute `remote_id` in DB but your object `user` still does not have this value. You should `reload` object to fetch this data from DB.

```
before { @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user) }

it "has_remote_id" do
  @user.save! && @user.reload
  expect(@user.remote_id).not_not be_nil
end
```